# Flex Remoting error

Tags: apache-flex

I have a Flex and Java application and i am using BlazeDS between flex and java.
Generally my application works fine. I observed when ever i try fetch data little faster(not giving gap between two fetch commands) then i am getting the error

"Server error :faultCode:Channel.Call.Failed faultString:'error' faultDetail:'NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed'"

I guess when ever load is increasing on BlazeDs, i am getting the error.
I am calling the java service using following code

```
    service = new RemoteObject();
service.showBusyCursor=true;
service.destination = "javaDataService"; 
service.requestTimeout = 50;   
var call:Object = service.findAll();
call.addResponder(this);
```

This problem is coming randomly and i am running out of all ideas.
Please help me out to solve this issue.
Regards,
Aj

Answer (score 1):

Its been a while since I worked with BlazeDS, but of the many oddities it had was that it couldn't support more than 3 concurrent calls.    Perhaps this is the problem why it works as long as you don't go too fast?